# How to hide job hunting from current employer?

Tags: interviewing, job-change, notice-period

I have decided to leave my current employer (see this: https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60074/am-i-bad-employee-or-bad-fit-or-did-i-pick-i-bad-job-career-for-me) and I have completed a few phone interviews/screens and attended 2 face to face interviews and I expect to get more calls this coming week (due to the holiday being over). I wonder how can I hide my interviews(my preparations) and any spontaneous job phone calls from coworkers/boss/employer?

Specifically...

1. How do I ensure nobody in the office suspects I am taking my lunch to interview or that I look like I am going to an interview?
2. How do I schedule interview times that reduce suspicion from my employer?
3. How do I hide my "schedule" when every moment of my day(out of office, return times from lunch, days off, etc) must be recorded on a team public calendar? (All days off and breaks exceeding 30 minutes must be approved by my supervisor in writing at least 2 weeks before the date.)
4. How can I keep enthusiasm up in order to get my work done? (I tend to be a clock watcher at work now)
5. How do I make my leaving be on good terms even when I do not plan on returning to this employer?
6. How do I combat a CNC (non-disclosure agreement)?

Comment: That's a lot of questions fp one post. I'm sure at least some of them are already addressed on the site. Please search the site for what you can find, and then edit your post to trim it down to one core issue.

Comment: Why bother? Just take the morning off or afternoon so you are not pressured. People do understand that people move between jobs. (My last job I turned up in a suit and people asked - I said "i have a job interview this afternoon" - the reply was good luck

Comment: For 5 and 6, work out which is more important to you as they're mutually exclusive. As a hint: don't be a dick.

Comment: Just leave on good terms. Does not hurt you. A reference from them might be useful in future. Also what comes around goes around, and you may end up working with one of your former colleagues.

Comment: EdHeal, that is hilarious! I wish my coworkers were like that (probably would not be leaving if they were) instead I am sure they are scouring my LinkedIn and other places to see where I am going and trash talk about me. -- Phillip Kendall, true. Though I guess I can have more fun when she gets fired after I leave and she fails to keep up on everything. :)

Comment: I think you are being a bit paranoid.

Comment: @EdHeal Nah, I saw the same thing happen to the past 4 coworkers that left and the weeks before their notice. Though, I find it funny on some level that they go through all that for a single employee.

Comment: A desire to stick it to you boss is not healthy and not a good long (or even short term) game plan.  I she is that incompetent she should not be able figure out you are leaving.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I think I figured a wonderful answer to the predicament. Simple, yet effective. My leaving will be equal to "sticking it to her", and there is nothing I can do to prevent that. Elegant, no?

Comment: What does CNC stand for if you meant an NDA?

Comment: Voting to close: Questions asking for advice on what to do are not practical answerable questions.  Also far too many questions in one as well.

Comment: @JBKing That is what my company labeled the document as but it is a combination of a non-disclosure agreement and non-compete agreement. Sorry for any confusion.

Answer (score 4):

Do the prep on your own time.

If you're paranoid about the overdressing issue, schedule vacation days for the interviews. Or just say "yeah, fancy date tnight." (Or concert, if you dress for those.) Or change just before the interview, in an offsite rest room if necessary.

Sounds like you should be scheduling vacation now, and then either get the other company to talk to you on one of those days or -- since the time's already reserved -- try to reschedule those vacation days a bit (which may be easier than getting them cleared). But any company worth talking to will understand schedule issues and won't mind waiting a few weeks if necessary.

If you're watching The clock, you're not going to do well anywhere. Ditto you "stick it to the man" attitude. You are only sabotaging yourself. A pro is someone who tries to do their best work even when they don't feel like it. While they are paying you, you owe them full time. If you can't cope with that, the honest thing to do is quit now.

Re leaving on good terms: See previous paragraph. Whether you like the guy has nothing to do with doing your job. Period.

Comment: Thanks for the advice! I watch the clock because the environment is so toxic and broken so I want to spend as little time there as possible. As for the "stick it to the man" it is just a personal thing since I know she will drag my name through the mud and I have no intention of helping her sinking ship...nonetheless, I might consider just focusing on a key task our department has yet to complete (and it needs to get done)...could last me some time and does not help her in the long run.

Comment: Watching the clock will make you feel worse, not better. And it will make you perform worse, get you into more trouble, and ... Seriously, you're reacting petulantly and digging yourself deeper into the hole, and until you fix that you're going to keep screwing youself out of jobs.

Comment: I doubt I am digging myself into a hole at all. It is no secret that the department has failed and it was long before I got there and 1 person can only do so much. I perform above expectations where I am, I never have had a manager, executive, or coworker complain saying that I am not working or not busy, usually the opposite ("Want an assistant?", "Take a break, you are working to death." and they are sincere). Thanks for the advice though! I definitely have observed an hour can feel like a day.

Comment: @keshlam, not sure what you mean by "[companies] won't mind waiting a few weeks [to interview]". They most certainly will, especially for junior positions. The OP should just schedule as many interviews as feasible and take days and half-days as needed on short-notice. No need for him to drag it out longer.

Comment: @teego1967: May depend on what industry you're working in, or the size of the company, or the number of positionx being hired for. _Especially_ for junior positions,  I'm used to the company taking a month or three to interview everyone before picking top candidates from that batch. Others, of course, may do things differently... but I still feel that anyone who can't work with you to scbedule is sending signals that _I_, at leas/, would be warned off by.

Comment: `A pro is someone who tries to do their best work even when they don't feel like it.` This.  Also remember the (very) high possibility that somewhere in your career you will work with at least one person from this company again.  What impression of you do you wish to leave?  One of you as a professional who transcends a poor workplace, or as someone who wastes time, complains and hold grudges?  Hint:  Guess which one I _wouldn't_ hire!

Comment: I should elaborate on what "prep" meant in the context of my case. I mean making sure I have my interview materials, time to relax into the interview, etc. @JaneS Rest assured that I do my job, better than most, but that doesn't mean I enjoy it when I work with a toxic company and people who make work harder without the need to. If I work with anyone of these people again I would be watching the news to see how hell froze over.

Comment: Do the prep on your own time.